# pybind11 embed leaves uncleaned processes

Tags: python-2.7, c++11, python-embedding, pybind11

sim_wrapper.h

```
#pragma once
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace n_sim
{
    namespace py = pybind11;
    // __attribute__ needed for pybind to work
    class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Sim
    {
    public:
        Sim();
        // python sim class instance we're using
        py::object sim;

    private:
        // python module want to load into our C++ code.
        py::module SimWrapModule;
        // Needed to initialize pybind. As soon as this goes out of scope, pybind is un-initialized.
        py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    };
}
```

sim_wrapper.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sim_wrapper.h"

using namespace n_sim;

Sim::Sim()
{
    // import python module
    SimWrapModule = py::module::import("wrapper");
    // catch return values from python functions
    sim = SimWrapModule.attr("initialize_sim")();
}

int main()
{
    Sim* SimWrap = new Sim();
    py::str name = SimWrap->sim.attr("name");
    std::cout << name.cast<std::string>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When this program is run it print the `name` and program closes but it leaves three uncleaned processes. Tried `gstack` with these processes and all have output like,

```
$ gstack 22763
#0  0x00000036f42df3c8 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f012a43867b in poll_poll () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
#2  0x00007f01346b50cb in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#3  0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#4  0x00007f0134631190 in function_call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#5  0x00007f01345ff793 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#6  0x00007f01346b1956 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#7  0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#8  0x00007f01346b5ab5 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#9  0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#10 0x00007f01346b5ab5 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#11 0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#12 0x00007f0134631265 in function_call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#13 0x00007f01345ff793 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#14 0x00007f01346b1956 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#15 0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#16 0x00007f01346b5ab5 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#17 0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#18 0x00007f0134631265 in function_call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#19 0x00007f01345ff793 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#20 0x00007f01346b1956 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#21 0x00007f01346b5b63 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#22 0x00007f01346b5b63 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#23 0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#24 0x00007f0134631190 in function_call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#25 0x00007f01345ff793 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#26 0x00007f013460e21d in instancemethod_call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#27 0x00007f01345ff793 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#28 0x00007f013466ac6f in slot_tp_init () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#29 0x00007f01346697ef in type_call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#30 0x00007f01345ff793 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#31 0x00007f01346b2281 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#32 0x00007f01346b5b63 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#33 0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#34 0x00007f01346b5ab5 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#35 0x00007f01346b65cd in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#36 0x00007f0134631190 in function_call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#37 0x00007f01345ff793 in PyObject_Call () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#38 0x00007f01346aff67 in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords () from /opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#39 0x0000000000417299 in pybind11::detail::simple_collector<(pybind11::return_value_policy)1>::call(_object*) const ()
#40 0x0000000000413c48 in _ZNK8pybind116detail10object_apiINS0_8accessorINS0_17accessor_policies8str_attrEEEEclILNS_19return_value_policyE1EJEEENS_6objectEDpOT0_ ()
#41 0x00000000004054b7 in n_sim::Sim::Sim() ()
#42 0x00000000004055f5 in main ()
```

Any idea on what need to be done to cleanly run this program?

Answer (score 1):

This was happening because some of the resources held by Python module were not getting released. Wrote python function `stop` in python module and called that in C++ at the end solved this issue.

Just before return I am now calling `SimWrap->sim.attr("stop")();`

Comment: Add more details for this to helpful for others...perhaps an ex.